# Opening an Activity that contains only a Dialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a `Dialog` that it's inside of an `Activity`, and want to show this `Activity` without background, I only want to show the `Dialog`.

I'm doing this `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifyNetworkWifi.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the `Activity` it's a simple `Alert Dialog`

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(this.getTitle() + " decision");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    // set positive button: Yes message
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });
    // set negative button: No message
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // cancel the alert box and put a Toast to the user
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose a negative answer",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    // set neutral button: Exit the app message
    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Exit the app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // exit the app and go to the HOME
            Main2Activity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show alert
    alertDialog.show();
```

I didn't set a content view, I just delete it and added this line

```
setTheme(R.style.TUPUTAMADRE);
```

This `Style` is

```
<style name="TUPUTAMADRE" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I don't know why is showing to me a black screen behind the `Dialog`, I just want to show this dialog....
What I'm doing wrong?

### LOGCAT ERROR

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
 at com.tupits.dialogwithnetworkavaliable.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:15)
```

Comment: How should it show any background if you didn't set any contentView?

Comment: I want a "Float activity" means that only shows the dialog, for example on my code I have a notification and I want when I press the Notification shows the Dialog but it shows the Dialog with a blackscreen

Comment: like the whatsapp dialog when you get a new message?

Comment: Why does this need to be a separate activity if its only purpose is to show a dialog?

Comment: NO, I mean when I click a notification doesn't matter where I'm (on my activity, or on a game) it shows a Dialog.

Comment: @AxelRos try using `<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />` in your manifest file

Comment: @dharms Becase on my code this Activity makes a lot of tasks to show this Dialog with the correct information

Comment: @qwertz tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the entire activity code?

Comment: You could have a static utility that generates and shows the dialog without it being an activity. Just a suggestion.

Comment: how could I do this?

Comment: Create a static method that takes in an activity and whatever other parameters you need to determine how to populate the dialog. Then move all of your AlertDialogBuilder logic there and use the activity parameter for the constructor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

try this code as your style

Comment: It oppens a new activity with the same title as the first Activity

Comment: @AxelRos how is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use Android theme in your manifest for activity.